# location for product.tpl file in xcart

Tags: x-cart

I want to know the location of product details page. There are so many product tpl files there. so I do not even know is it product.tpl or product_detail.tpl. So please help.

Answer (score 1):

if you want product details page then it is in

> skin/commin_files/customer/main/product.tpl.(this is default if you have your new template then it can be different than common_files)

and if you want PHP file of product details. then it will be in the root directory with name,

> product.php